# How do you write spaces in a Column name during table creation in mySQL? In MSSQL, I can write [Column Name]. I have found no way for this in mySQL

Tags: mysql

How do you write spaces in a column name during table creation in mySQL? In MSSQL, I can write [Column Name] and create columns with spaces using brackets. . I have found no way for this in mySQL? Is it possible? Not that I want to do this, but I must due to third party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must put the name in backticks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
`W i t h S p a c e s` VARCHAR(33)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any SQL implementation should support *delimited identifiers*. This allows you to use whitespace, punctuation, international characters, or SQL reserved words in your table names and column names.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html says:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to
>   quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ```

Note that Microsoft SQL Server also supports double-quotes as identifier delimiters when you enable the QUOTED_IDENTIFERS option. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx

Standard SQL defines double-quotes as the only identifier delimiters. Unfortunately, both Microsoft and MySQL didn't get that memo.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using apostrophes and didn't work. Back ticks Thanks for the info.